# Determine if 2 binary trees are similar

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-tree, nodes

I am having trouble finding out if the number of nodes at each level is the same. The question and my code so far is provided below

Two binary trees are called similar sized if the number of nodes is the same at each level of the tree

Given the following:

```
class TreeNode {
    String nodeValue;
    TreeNode rightNode;
    TreeNode leftNode;

    TreeNode(String nodeValue, TreeNode rightNode, TreeNode leftNode) {
        this.nodeValue = nodeValue;
        this.rightNode = rightNode;
        this.leftNode = leftNode;
    }
}
```

The goal of this question is to write a function that will validate if two trees are similar sized.

The function should return true if this is correct and false otherwise

[image]

my code:

```
//implemented with java
class TreeNode {
    String nodeValue;
    TreeNode rightNode;
    TreeNode leftNode;

    TreeNode(String nodeValue, TreeNode rightNode, TreeNode leftNode) {
        this.nodeValue = nodeValue;
        this.rightNode = rightNode;
        this.leftNode = leftNode;
    }

    //function to return size of node, i.e. number of children
    int nodeSize() {
        //if node has both left and right child node
        if (this.rightNode.nodeValue != null && this.leftNode.nodeValue != null) {
            return 2;
        //if node has no child nodes
        } else if (this.rightNode.nodeValue == null && this.leftNode.nodeValue == null) {
            return 0;
        //if node just has either left or right child node
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    boolean similarSizedTrees(TreeNode firstTree, TreeNode secondTree) {
        //if both nodes have no child nodes
        if (firstTree.nodeSize() == 0 && secondTree.nodeSize() == 0) {
            return true;
        }

        //if both nodes have at least 1 child node
        if (firstTree.nodeSize() != 0 && secondTree.nodeSize() != 0) {
            return ((firstTree.nodeSize() == secondTree.nodeSize()) &&
                    similarSizedTrees(firstTree.leftNode, secondTree.leftNode) &&
                    similarSizedTrees(firstTree.leftNode, secondTree.rightNode));
        }

        //
        return false;
    }
}
```

What I am having trouble with is my code does not account for the number of nodes at each level.

Comment: If the question is 2 binary trees are similar or not. so why we have to check the number of nodes in each level of the trees?

Comment: Similar sized trees and similar trees, these two are different.

Comment: @BadhanSen I think that this is just a definition of *similarity* that is given upfront, no matter how much intuitive it is. This is what we call two tries that have the same count of node on each level.

Answer (score 1):

Your recursion based approach wouldn't work, because the number of nodes in the next level aren't influenced by which node each child descends from. You could modify your approach to use a simple level order traversal.

(Edit: adding @Piotr's explanation)
The basic idea is to count nodes on each level. In the example picture there is 1 node on level 1, 2 nodes on level 2 and 3 nodes on level 3 and finally 1 node on level 4. These numbers are exactly the same for both tree, even if they are not exactly the same. This algorithm is computing these counts for each level, and if discrepancy is found, it returns False. Otherwise it returns True in the end if both trees are similar. (I'm not well versed in Java, but you can easily translate the algorithm):

```
def similar(firstTree, secondTree):

    queue1, queue2 = queue(firstTree), queue(secondTree) # create queues for traversal
    # each queue stores all nodes in a given level 
    while queue1 and queue2:
        if len(queue1)!=len(queue2): # check base condition
            return False

        i = 0
        while i<len(queue1): # append all next level nodes for tree 1
            node = queue1.pop()
            if node.left:
                queue1.insert(node.left)
            if node.right:
                queue1.insert(node.right)
            i += 1

        i = 0
        while i<len(queue2): # append all next level nodes for tree 2
            node = queue2.pop()
            if node.left:
                queue2.insert(node.left)
            if node.right:
                queue2.insert(node.right)
            i += 1

    if queue1 or queue2:
        return False # either tree couldn't complete traversal because of different heights

    return True
```

Comment: I think that this code is correct, but it might be still not clear what is it doing for the author of this question. The basic idea is to count nodes on each level. In the example picture there is 1 node on level 1, 2 nodes on level 2 and 3 nodes on level 3 and finally 1 node on level 4. These numbers are exactly the same for both tree, even if they are not *exactly* the same. This algorithm is computing these counts for each level, and if discrepancy is found, it returns False. Otherwise it returns True in the end if both trees are similar.

Comment: @Piotr okay, thanks. I'll include your explanation in the answer as well

Answer (score -1):

A couple solutions can be found here: https://www.techiedelight.com/check-if-two-binary-trees-are-identical-not-iterative-recursive/

this is the recursive function shown from the link mentioned above tailored to your code.

```
 boolean similarSizedTrees(TreeNode x, TreeNode y) {
        // bottom of tree reached
        if (x == null && y == null) {
            return true;
        }
        // both trees are non-empty and the value of their root node matches,
        // recur for their left and right subtree
        return (x != null && y != null) && (x.key == y.key) &&
                    similarSizedTrees(x.left, y.left) &&
                    similarSizedTrees(x.right, y.right);
    }
```

EDIT: You could also keep count of the nodes at each level using two global int variables, one for each tree, as you traverse the tree increment each variable, then compare them together before continuing down to the next level.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution using recursion:

```
int find_height(TreeNode t){
    return (t == null)? 0 : 1 + Math.max(find_height(t.leftNode), find_height(t.rightNode));
}

boolean is_similar_tree(TreeNode l, TreeNode r){
    int l_height = find_height(l);
    int r_height = find_height(r);

    if(l_height != r_height)
        return false;

    int[] l_height_sums = new int[l_height];
    int[] r_height_sums = new int[r_height];

    is_similar_tree_helper(l, l_height_sums, l_height);
    is_similar_tree_helper(r, r_height_sums, r_height);

    return Arrays.equals(l_height_sums, r_height_sums);
}

void is_similar_tree_helper(TreeNode t, int[] table, int height){
    if(t == null || height == 0)
        return;

    table[height - 1]++;

    is_similar_tree_helper(t.leftNode, table, height - 1);
    is_similar_tree_helper(t.rightNode, table, height - 1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The idea is to count the number of nodes in each level, then check if the total number of levels of two trees are the same or not. If it is not the same then return false otherwise check each level count and compare the value. If two values are equal then return true otherwise false.

```
class TreeNode {
    String nodeValue;
    TreeNode rightNode;
    TreeNode leftNode;

    TreeNode(String nodeValue, TreeNode rightNode, TreeNode leftNode) {
        this.nodeValue = nodeValue;
        this.rightNode = rightNode;
        this.leftNode = leftNode;
    }
    
    
    public void countLevelNode(TreeNode root, int level, int[] sum) {
        if(root == null) return;
        sum[level]++;
        countLevelNode(root.leftNode, level + 1, sum);
        countLevelNode(root.rightNode, level + 1, sum);
        
    } 
    boolean similarSizedTrees(TreeNode firstTree, TreeNode secondTree) {
        int[] countFirstTreeNode = new int[1000];
        int[] countSecondTreeNode = new int[1000];
        int totalLevelofFirstTree = 0;
        int totalLevelofSecondTree = 0;

        countLevelNode(firstTree, totalLevelofFirstTree, countFirstTreeNode);
        countLevelNode(secondTree, totalLevelofSecondTree, countSecondTreeNode);

        if(totalLevelofFirstTree != totalLevelofSecondTree){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i < totalLevelofFirstTree; i++){
                if(countFirstTreeNode[i] != countSecondTreeNode[i]){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you initialize the global variables outside of similarSizedTrees()?  Calling the function more than once can lead to indeterminate behavior since the array is never reinitialized after the first call.

Comment: There is no specific reason. you can initialize inside the ```similarSizedTrees()``` method or also.

Comment: Thanks, @ShaanK for pointing out the case. I updated the code. Have a look, please.

Comment: Looks good, you could have always left the variable definitions global but I like how you just moved everything to be local.